# Black background when presenting modally view controller

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I have one problem when I see my view being presented with black BG color. Here is my code:

```
class Loader: UIViewController, NVActivityIndicatorViewable {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
    self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.view.isOpaque = false
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let frame = CGRect(x: width / 2, y: height / 2, width: 100, height: 100)
    let activityIndicatorView = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: frame, type: NVActivityIndicatorType.lineScale, color: GlobalVariables.stacksBlue, padding: 20)
    self.view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    activityIndicatorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    activityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    activityIndicatorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

And the extension where is call function:

```
extension UIViewController {
func showLoader() {
    let loader = Loader()
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
    self.present(loader, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
func hideLoader() {
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: Don't edit your question with an answer. If one of the answers below solved your issue, accept that question. If you came up with your own solution, post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
let loader = Loader()
loader.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true;
loader.definesPresentationContext = true;
loader.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(loader, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: it dissapeared :( Background is my content but there is no preloader on the screen being showed

Comment: remove any background setting lines and try

Comment: Nothing has changed. Loader does not appear. Only background content...

Comment: check by a print if viewDidLoad is called

Comment: set background color for the activity , may be it's color is same as presenting Vc's view

Answer (score 0):

You are saying:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
self.view.isOpaque = false
```

So the view itself is clear, and you are seeing the blackness of the window behind it.

Comment: there is content behind it. it cannot be black as I understood

Comment: No, there is no content behind it. You are doing a `currentContext` presentation. A `currentContext` presentation _replaces_ the current context; it has nothing _behind_ it. And if there is no current context, it defaults to a fullscreen presentation and we see the blackness of the window, just as I said.